# Windows phone 8 facebooksdk login and relogin

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on Windows Phone 8 application and I would like to integrate facebook login into the application. I downloaded Facebook and Facebook.Client nuget packages.

I followed this tutorial http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/tutorial/ and implemented login feature. My code looks like this:

```
async private void btnFacebookLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (!App.isAuthenticated)
   {
       App.isAuthenticated = true;
       await Authenticate();
   }
}


private async Task Authenticate()
{
    string message = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        session = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream");
        App.AccessToken = session.AccessToken;
        App.FacebookId = session.FacebookId;

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(LandingPage));
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {
        message = "Login failed! Exception details: " + e.Message;
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
        dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

The login works fine, but when I close my application and start it again the session object is lost.
When I push on the Login button and call the Authenticate() method the Facebook login dialog is not shown and the method App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream") returns session immediately. This is not too nice for the user.
In the application is button "Facebook login" and after the click is displayed logged user without any login form or any user interaction.
I don't know where is the session stored and howto check if any old session is available and will be returned back without Facebook login dialog.

Is there any way how to do this?

This is my version of the FacebookSessionClient

```
#region Assembly Facebook.Client.dll, v0.9.1.0
// D:\Work\packages\Facebook.Client.0.9.1-alpha\lib\wp8\Facebook.Client.dll
#endregion

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Facebook.Client
{
    public class FacebookSessionClient
    {
        public FacebookSessionClient(string appId);

        public string AppId { get; set; }
        public FacebookSession CurrentSession { get; }
        public bool LoginInProgress { get; set; }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public Task<FacebookSession> LoginAsync();
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public Task<FacebookSession> LoginAsync(string permissions);
        public void LoginWithApp();
        public void LoginWithApp(string permissions);
        public void LoginWithApp(string permissions, string state);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Log a user out of Facebook.
        public void Logout();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

Step 1:

```
_client = new FacebookSessionClient(yourAppId);
```

Step 2: ( Add LoggedIn property to FacebookSessionClient as below)

```
public bool LoggedIn
{
    get
    {
        return CurrentSession != null && CurrentSession.Expires > DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

I also changed the FacebookSessionClient replacing the existing CurrentSession property with

```
public FacebookSession CurrentSession
{
    get
    {
        return FacebookSessionCacheProvider.Current.GetSessionData();
    }
}
```

Step 3:

```
if(!_client.LoggedIn)
{
    _client.LoginAsync("basic_info,publish_actions,read_stream,user_photos");
}
else
{
    //just use the _client variable
}
```

Facebook Client worries to store it's session and reload it on next time you open the app.

This is what I have in my FacebookSessionClient.cs

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="FacebookSessionClient.cs" company="The Outercurve Foundation">
//    Copyright (c) 2011, The Outercurve Foundation. 
//
//    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
//    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
//    You may obtain a copy of the License at
//      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
//    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
//    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
//    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
//    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
//    limitations under the License.
// </copyright>
// <author>Nathan Totten (ntotten.com) and Prabir Shrestha (prabir.me)</author>
// <website>https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facbook-winclient-sdk</website>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
#if NETFX_CORE
using Windows.Security.Authentication.Web;
#endif

namespace Facebook.Client
{
    public class FacebookSessionClient
    {
        public string AppId { get; set; }
        public bool LoginInProgress { get; set; }

        public FacebookSession CurrentSession
        {
            get
            {
                return FacebookSessionCacheProvider.Current.GetSessionData();
            }
        }

        public FacebookSessionClient(string appId)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(appId))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("appId");
            }
            AppId = appId;

            // Send analytics to Facebook
            SendAnalytics(appId);
        }

        private static bool AnalyticsSent = false;

        private void SendAnalytics(string FacebookAppId = null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!AnalyticsSent)
                {
                    AnalyticsSent = true;

#if !(WINDOWS_PHONE)
                    Version assemblyVersion = typeof(FacebookSessionClient).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Version;
#else
                    string assemblyVersion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.Split(',')[1].Split('=')[1];
#endif
                    string instrumentationURL = String.Format("https://www.facebook.com/impression.php/?plugin=featured_resources&payload=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22microsoft_csharpsdk%22%2C%22appid%22%3A%22{0}%22%2C%22version%22%3A%22{1}%22%7D",
                            FacebookAppId == null ? String.Empty : FacebookAppId, assemblyVersion);

                    HttpHelper helper = new HttpHelper(instrumentationURL);

                    // setup the read completed event handler to dispose of the stream once the results are back
                    helper.OpenReadCompleted += (o, e) => { if (e.Error == null) using (var stream = e.Result) { }; };
                    helper.OpenReadAsync();
                }
            }
            catch { } //ignore all errors
        }

#if WP8
        public void LoginWithApp()
        {
            LoginWithApp(null);
        }

        public void LoginWithApp(string permissions)
        {
            LoginWithApp(permissions, null);
        }

        public void LoginWithApp(string permissions, string state)
        {
            AppAuthenticationHelper.AuthenticateWithApp(this.AppId, permissions, state);
        }
#endif

        public async Task<FacebookSession> LoginAsync()
        {
            return await LoginAsync(null, false);
        }

        public async Task<FacebookSession> LoginAsync(string permissions)
        {
            return await LoginAsync(permissions, false);
        }

        internal async Task<FacebookSession> LoginAsync(string permissions, bool force)
        {
            if (LoginInProgress)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Login in progress.");
            }

            LoginInProgress = true;
            try
            {
                var session = FacebookSessionCacheProvider.Current.GetSessionData();
                if (session == null)
                {
                    // Authenticate
                    var authResult = await PromptOAuthDialog(permissions, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);

                    FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(authResult.AccessToken);
                    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    parameters["fields"] = "id";

                    var result = await client.GetTaskAsync("me", parameters);
                    var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)result;

                    session = new FacebookSession
                    {
                        AccessToken = authResult.AccessToken,
                        Expires = authResult.Expires,
                        FacebookId = (string)dict["id"],
                    };

                }
                else
                {
                    // Check if we are requesting new permissions
                    bool newPermissions = false;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(permissions))
                    {
                        var p = permissions.Split(',');
                        newPermissions =
                            session.CurrentPermissions.Join(p, s1 => s1, s2 => s2, (s1, s2) => s1).Count() != p.Length;
                    }

                    // Prompt OAuth dialog if force renew is true or
                    // if new permissions are requested or 
                    // if the access token is expired.
                    if (force || newPermissions || session.Expires <= DateTime.UtcNow)
                    {
                        var authResult = await PromptOAuthDialog(permissions, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);
                        if (authResult != null)
                        {
                            session.AccessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
                            session.Expires = authResult.Expires;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Set the current known permissions
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(permissions))
                {
                    var p = permissions.Split(',');
                    session.CurrentPermissions = session.CurrentPermissions.Union(p).ToList();
                }

                // Save session data
                FacebookSessionCacheProvider.Current.SaveSessionData(session);

            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                string msg = x.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                LoginInProgress = false;
            }

            return CurrentSession;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Log a user out of Facebook.
        /// </summary>
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1726:UsePreferredTerms", MessageId = "Logout", Justification = "Logout is preferred by design")]
        public void Logout()
        {
            try
            {
                FacebookSessionCacheProvider.Current.DeleteSessionData();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {

            }
        }

        private async Task<FacebookOAuthResult> PromptOAuthDialog(string permissions, WebAuthenticationOptions options)
        {
            // Use WebAuthenticationBroker to launch server side OAuth flow

            Uri startUri = GetLoginUrl(permissions);
            Uri endUri = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html");

            var result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(options, startUri, endUri);


            if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            else if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.UserCancel)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            var client = new FacebookClient();
            var authResult = client.ParseOAuthCallbackUrl(new Uri(result.ResponseData));
            return authResult;
        }

        private Uri GetLoginUrl(string permissions)
        {
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            parameters["client_id"] = AppId;
            parameters["redirect_uri"] = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
            parameters["response_type"] = "token";
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
            parameters["display"] = "touch";
            parameters["mobile"] = true;
#else
            parameters["display"] = "popup";
#endif

            // add the 'scope' only if we have extendedPermissions.
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(permissions))
            {
                // A comma-delimited list of permissions
                parameters["scope"] = permissions;
            }

            var client = new FacebookClient();
            return client.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// client.GetTaskAsync(path, parameters);
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path"> example: "me"</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">example: "basic_info" or "basic_info, other_parameters"</param>
        /// <returns>Dictionary with result</returns>
        public async Task<IDictionary<string, object>> GetTaskAsync(string path, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
        {
            FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(CurrentSession.AccessToken);
            var result = await client.GetTaskAsync(path, parameters);
            var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)result;
            return dict;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// client.PostAsync(path, parameters);
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">example: "me"</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">example: "basic_info" or "basic_info, other_parameters"</param>
        /// <returns>Dictionary with result</returns>
        public async Task<IDictionary<string, object>> PostTaskAsync(string path, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
        {
            FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(CurrentSession.AccessToken);
            TaskCompletionSource<object> task = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            client.PostCompleted += (sen, ev) =>
                                        {
                                            if (ev.Cancelled) task.TrySetCanceled();
                                            if (ev.Error != null) task.TrySetException(ev.Error);
                                            task.TrySetResult(ev.GetResultData());
                                        };
            client.PostAsync(path, parameters);
            var result = await task.Task;
            var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)result;
            return dict;
        }

        public bool LoggedIn
        {
            get
            {
                return CurrentSession != null && CurrentSession.Expires > DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The FacebookSessionClient class does not have the LoggedIn property.

Comment: Just to make sure it always works check out my updated answer I posted my customized FacebookSessionClient that enhances CurrentSession handling.

Comment: I don't know if I follow you exactly. This is your own FacebookSessionClient or it is FacebookSessionClient you downloaded from FB sdk?

Comment: I actually downloaded the source code and adapted it to keep the session and load it correctly. I don't remember why it wasn't loading corectly